# How to manually add auido files in photo gallery in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone programming. **Can any body tell me that how to manually add audio files inside the photo gallery?** I got some link like we can manually add video inside the simulator but that is only video. I want audio files,too. I have searched in google but I didnt find any where how to add audios files inside photo gallery.

Please can any body tell me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone's photo gallery does not support audio files.

Comment: where i have to add audio files

Answer (score 0):

You can not add audio files to Photo Library. But you can use [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765) for same approach.

Also refer [AddMusic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845) demo. `AddMusic` demonstrates basic use of iPod library access, part of the Media Player framework. You use iPod library access to play songs, audio books, and audio podcasts that are synced from a user's desktop iTunes library. This sample uses the Media Player framework's built-in user interface for choosing music.

AddMusic also demonstrates how to mix application audio with iPod library audio